# Android: Make several buttons use the same onClickListener object

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am new to android and I am trying to create a tic tac toe application. I tried doing this:

```
board[index1][index2].setOnClickListener(bbch);
```

where bbch is an object of a class I created called boardButtonClickHandler which implements OnClickListener. This did not work and pressing the buttons had no effect.
However the following code works properly:

```
board[index1][index2].setOnClickListener(new boardButtonClickHandler());
```

which is doing what it is supposed to do perfectly. Is there any way that I can make several buttons use the same object?

Comment: Do you already have these Buttons defined in the xml and do you need to use a separate class or can you just reuse a function in the Activity?

Comment: Did you remember to actually instantiate bbch with new at any point?  Because that code should work as long as bbch is valid.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks! I had just declared bbch. I did not initialize it in onCreate. I thought that if I just declared bbch it would be automatically initialized using the constructor with no arguments.

Comment: Nope, java doesn't do that.  If its a member variable of a class, it will be set to null by default.  If its a local variable, it has no default value, but shouldn't compile unless its set to a value before use.